# How to Tell JPA the prefered DataType

Tags: java, database, jpa, types, eclipselink

If I use JPA (EclipseLink) to create tables a String type results in a varchar2(255). How could I tell JPA (via Annotation) to create a varchar2(20) attribute.

If I have a List JPA creates a BLOB(4000) but I would like a varchar2 (my serialized object's string is short)

How is this possible? Do I have to do it by hand?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to use the columnDefinition property of the @Column annotation. i.e.

```
@Column(columnDefinition="varchar2(20)")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...will try it tomorrow

Comment: -1 as @Pascals answer below is better. It avoids the compatibility issue caused by explicitly referencing the data type in your code.

Comment: This is useful for situations when you need to tell JPA that column is NVARCHAR not VARCHAR(255), but this not the case.

Comment: Does JPA auto convert Java String datatype to SQL Number type for persistence purpose?

Comment: Not a portable solution.

Answer (score 30):

> If I use JPA (EclipseLink) to create tables a String type results in a varchar2(255). How could I tell JPA (via Annotation) to create a varchar2(20) attribute.

Using the `columnDefinition` can break portability from one database to another. For a string-valued column, prefer using the `length` element (which defaults to 255):

```
@Column(length=20)
String someString;
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the portability issues related to columnDefinition.

Comment: I think you can improve your answer telling about the attribute for numeric values.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the `length` on your `@Column` annotation, as such:

```
@Column(length = 20)
```

Note that length is only for text columns. For numeric, you can use `precision` and `scale`.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Column(name = "doc_number", columnDefinition = "varchar2(20)")
```

Please, try that.

Comment: It's not portable solution

Comment: Not a generic solution.