# How to tell the jpa converter the type of the mapped column in the database?

Tags: java, database, jpa

How to tell the jpa converter the type of the mapped column in the database?
i have a field of type X that must be stored using xml data type in the database i created a converter that parse x to xml and recreate x using xml. my problem is that jpa expecting the column in the database to be Byte array not xml and when i try to persist the entity that contian x and exception thrown telling me that x is xml not byte array , i am using postgre as engine.

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088400/how-to-tell-jpa-the-prefered-datatype?rq=1) question

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: i am using eclipse-link.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type in the annotation:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="varchar(50)")
```

All of the following should be overridden (i.e. describe them all within columndefinition, if appropriate):
•length
•precision
•scale
•nullable
•unique

i.e. the column DDL will consist of: name + columndefinition and nothing else.

Comment: please recheck the question you have misunderstood it