# Schema validation exception for mapping ENUM Type MySQL to Hibernate Entity Enum

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, enums

I am currently facing issue while trying to map MYSQL ENUM type to my Hibernate JPA enum type. I get a schema validation error.
I have a simple enum in Java:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

The corresponding column definition for this is in MySQL Table is:

```
`gender` enum('MALE','FEMALE') DEFAULT NULL,
```

The annotations in the Entity class for this particular attribute is:

```
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name = "gender", columnDefinition="enum('MALE','FEMALE')")
   private Gender gender;
```

I get an error as :

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [gender]
>   in table [`...`]; found [enum (Types#CHAR)], but expecting
>   [`enum('MALE','FEMALE')` (Types#VARCHAR)]

I have tried not using the columnDefinition in @Column annotation and the error is:

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [gender] in
>   table [`...`]; found [enum (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255)
>   (Types#VARCHAR)]

I also tried writing my own converter by as per the instructions in:https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-enum-mappings/#customizedMapping
but that didnt help either.

Any idea?

Note: When i was using EclipseLink there were no issues with my entity for the same DB definition and without explicitly defining my columnDefinition in @Column. I started facing this issue when i removed EclipseLink. The project uses Spring Data JPA right now. Hibernate Core 5.3.14 being used.

Comment: What if you don't use the @Column annotation at all?

Comment: If you don't need the enum values as Strings in the database, you could use EnumType.ORDINAL instead of EnumType.STRING

Comment: If i don't use @Column notation at all this is the schema validation error: found [enum (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]

Comment: Right now, i dont want to change how the cloumn is defined in the DB.

Comment: Oh so the problem is the column is already created and it's mismatching with your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088400/how-to-tell-jpa-the-prefered-datatype ?

Comment: The DB column is already defined. The project was using eclipse link to connect to the already existing table. When i removed eclipse link and using spring data jpa this pops up as an issue of mapping the DB column to my entity.

Comment: So have you tried @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(255)") as mentioned in the linked question?

Comment: Yeah, i tried varchar as the column definition. Again the found always complains of enum (Types#CHAR)] so varchar doesnt come up as a match either.

Comment: I tried using annotated Type hibernate annotations like this:
Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.EnumType",
         parameters = {
               @Parameter(name  = "enumClass", value = "<package structure>.Gender"),
               @Parameter(name = "type", value = "1111"),
               @Parameter(name = "useNamed", value = "true")
         })

but somehow the enum is type is not being picked up when i use Type. It defaults to type trying to match enum of Type#CHAR to integer

Comment: Since the table/DB is already created i have right now disabled spring auto ddl in my config. This solves the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, we just needed to add the column definition to the mapping:

```
@Basic
    @Column(name = "stripe_setup_intent_status", columnDefinition = "enum('SUCCESS', 'FAILED', 'WAITING')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SetupIntentStatus stripeSetupIntentStatus;
```

We are using hibernate `5.6.15` and spring `2.7.9`