# Using varchar without specifying the Database - varchar(MAX) = 4,000?

Tags: sql, database, jpa

Based on this [How to Tell JPA the prefered DataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088400/how-to-tell-jpa-the-prefered-datatype)  (8 years old) Question, I should use 'length' in the column definition

The max value for varchar in mariadb is: [65,532](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/varchar/)
and based on [this](https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/datatypes/text) i can create the following table:

```
| DB  | varchar(max) |
| --- | ---|
| MariaDB / MySQL | 65,532 |
| Oracle  |  4,000 |
| SQL Server | 2,097,152|
| PostgreSQL | 1,000,000 or 1,048,576 |
```

I need column with at least 30,000 characters. How could I archive this without making my software depending on some specific database? Or should I process without the indexing that comes with the varchar and use @lob for this kind of usage?

Comment: Why does the table exists in the preview but didn't rendered here?

Comment: You cannot write database independent code for this purpose.

Comment: do you want the column to handle 30k utf-8 characters, that's up to 30k * 4 bytes, or the column to handle 30000 bytes ?

Comment: Yes, I want to use utf-8 characters. So Oracles varchar can only handle 1k chars